# How to tie a Hudson job to a user who has access to run MSIExec

Tags: hudson

I have a batch file that calls "MSIExec /X {MyGUID} /qn". This runs successfully when run with my admin user. When I run it as a Window Batch command from a Hudson job it fails with "T�h�e� �i�n�s�t�a�l�l�a�t�i�o�n� �s�o�u�r�c�e� �f�o�r� �t�h�i�s� �p�r�o�d�u�c�t� �i�s� �n�o�t� �a�v�a�i�l�a�b�l�e�.� � �V�e�r�i�f�y� �t�h�a�t� �t�h�e� �s�o�u�r�c�e� �e�x�i�s�t�s� �a�n�d� �t�h�a�t� �y�o�u� �c�a�n� �a�c�c�e�s�s� �i�t�.�
"

I am inclined to think that the issue is that the job is started by the "anonymous" user rather than my admin user.

How in hudson do I "tie" the job to be run under the admin user?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Andrew

Comment: Can you give us the beginning of {MyGUID}? If it starts with HKEY_CURRENT_USER, you might not be able to reach that key at all.

Comment: It is auto generated time-based GUID from a web GUID generator of the form X9XX9X99-9X9X-99X9-99X9-XX9999XX9X99.

If I search the registry for this GUID all instances appear under HKLM.  Which I assume is default behaviour for the installer. THe installer sets ALL_USERS to 1, which has worked.  If I log in as a non-admin account the application is installed and appears in their program files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options, the first one is, running Hudson under an Admin user (usually a bad idea) or use the `runas` command. To avoid entering a password you might need to use the `/savecred` option.

BTW, did you read the error message? Here is the readable version of it:

> "The installation source for this
>   product is not available.  Verify that
>   the source exists and that you can
>   access it. "

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it did not work.  My batch file is:

@ECHO OFF
ECHO "Uninstalling application..."
runas /savecred /user:adminUser MsiExec.exe /X{myGuid} /qn /log UninstallLog.txt
ECHO "Uninstallation of application completed."
Exit 0

I call this batch file as a Windows Batch Step from hudson like so:

trunk/Uninstall.bat.

The job reports success but nothing is done.  The application remains installed.

It I manually run the batch file with the adminUser from a cmd prompt it works perfectly.

Why won't it work from Hudson?

Comment: Have a look at the KB article from Microsoft. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306541 --- Did you save the credentials for the account that hudson is using? The credentials that you save will only be available for the user saving the credentials. I am not aware that the localSystem, localService, or the NetworkService can store credentials.

Comment: Is there something in the Uninstall.log?

Comment: I have 'Run Hudson as a Windows Service' after launching it initially via JNLP.

I can stop the hudson service and hudson is still up.  Therefore, what user is hudson running as?

I'm using Windows 2003 SP1, not Windows XP.

Comment: That sounds weird that hudson still runs after launching it as a service. Sounds more like there is a second instance of Hudson still running. I am not sure what you see in the task manager when starting hudson via jnlp. If you start it as a service you will see an Hudson.exe. Check the Task Manager for any other Hudson instance running (may might need to check "Show processes from all user accounts"). If that doesn't help, try to shutdown the server by accessing `http://server/hudson/exit`. Don't forget to login if security is enabled.

Comment: I am running the service as the administrator account....jobs still start as the anonymous user in Hudson.  That said I have a user with the same name as the admin user in hudson participating in the continuous integration game.  How do I get jobs to start as this user?

Comment: If I set Security in hudson and log in as the user with the same name as my windows admin user the Uninstall job will run successfully.

Getting closer, but the Install is not working.  I get the message: "This installation package could not be opened.  Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package."

Even though the step before MsiExec.exe /i eStoreAdminWix.msi /qn /log InstallLog.txt is to change directory to where the msi is.

Why can't the install command run?

Comment: BTW, what Do you mean by the Job runs under the Admin user?? Do you mean that Hudson states: "Job started by.."? This are not the permissions that the OS sees, the job will always be with the permissions of the user that the Hudson service runs on.

Comment: I need to do this and it doesn't work for me.  It's really a bad design decision by the Hudson (Jenkins) team to not provide a way to impersonate another user while running a build job.   (In other words, putting RUNAS directly into the Jenkins/Hudson product).

Comment: You can try to use 'su' or 'runas' (which is a dos command), for most cases this works without an issue.